# C++ linked list implementation

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list

i am working on an assignment where i am asked to implement a linked list in c++. so far everything is working great except for when i am creating a new list. in my method `create_list()`. after i assign content and an id number to my `Field` and try to call `GetNext()` i get an error saying: `Request for member 'GetNext()' in 'Node' which is a non-class type '*Field'.` I'm still new to the C++ syntax and object oriented programming. What am I doing wrong? I thought by using the line `Field *Node = new Field(SIZE, EMPTY);` that my variable `Node` would be of class type `Field`...?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

typedef enum { EMPTY, OCCUPIED } FIELDTYPE;

// Gameboard Size
int SIZE;  

class Field {

private:
int _SquareNum; 
FIELDTYPE _Content; 
Field* _Next;

public: 
// Constructor
Field() { }

// Overload Constructor
Field(int SquareNum, FIELDTYPE Entry) { _SquareNum = SquareNum; _Content = Entry; }

// Get the next node in the linked list
Field* GetNext() { return _Next; }

// Set the next node in the linked list
void SetNext(Field *Next) { _Next = Next; }

// Get the content within the linked list
FIELDTYPE GetContent() { return _Content; }

// Set the content in the linked list
void SetContent(FIELDTYPE Content) { _Content = Content; }

// Get square / location 
int GetLocation() { return _SquareNum; }

// Print the content
void Print() { 

    switch (_Content) {

        case OCCUPIED: 
            cout << "Field " << _SquareNum << ":\tOccupied\n"; 
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Field " << _SquareNum << ":\tEmpty\n";
            break;
    }

} 

}*Gameboard;
```

here is my create_list() method:

```
void create_list()
{
int Element; 


cout << "Enter the size of the board: ";
cin >> SIZE; 
for(Element = SIZE; Element > 0; Element--){
    Field *Node = new Field(SIZE, EMPTY);
    Node.GetNext() = Gameboard; // line where the error is 
    Gameboard = Node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No in the declaration

```
Field *Node = new Field(SIZE, EMPTY);
```

Node is of type *pointer* to Field.

The fix is simple if you have a pointer to a class and you want to access a member of that class use `->`.

```
Node->GetNext() = Gameboard;
```

I think your code has other errors, and I don't think that even with this 'fix' it's going to work. Probably what you really want is

```
Node->SetNext(Gameboard);
```

Answer (score 3):

`.` is used for addressing members in objects and references to objects. `Node`, however, is a *pointer to* an object. So you need to turn it into a reference before you can use it with `.`. This means doing `(*Node).GetNext()`. Or you can use the shorthand: `Node->GetNext()` - these two are exactly equivalent.

A good mnemonic to use is that you use the pointy operator with pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Node.GetNext()`, but `Node` is a pointer. You need to use the `->` operator instead of the `.` operator, as in `Node->GetNext()`.

Comment: tried this but now am getting this error: "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Answer (score 0):

The function must returns a reference value if you want to set as a l-value.
You code need some changes:

```
// Get the next node in the linked list
Field& GetNext() { return *_Next; }
```

then you can use the function as a l-value

```
Node->GetNext() = *Gameboard;
```